# return value of [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height on iphone 6

Tags: ios, size, iphone-6

I am running my code on iphone 6 device, on portrait mode.

```
NSLog(@"main screen height : %f", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
```

Why does it return 568.0 and not 667.0?

Mode on iPhone is Standard - not Zoomed.

EDIT : This happens even on simulator - when I choose device to be iphone 6.

Comment: You need to add the iPhone 6/6+ launch images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the splash image for iPhone 6, then it will work as you want

Click on images.xcassets, click on attribute inspector and choose iOS 8.0 and Later

[image: choose iOS 8.0 and Later]

then you will get option for two extra launch image like below
Drag drop the retina size image for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus in **Retina HD 4.7** and **Retina HD 5.5** respectively

[image: Add launch image for Retina HD]

Comment: Hmm, nothing changed - on Assets catalog in xCode, I have set both images under Launch images - both for 2x and the retina 4 (iPhone portair 7,8)

Comment: You need to add an image _for the iPhone 6_. Without that image, Apple assumes that the app cannot handle the iPhone 6, and just blows up iPhone 5 graphics.

Comment: I have edited the answer and shown in detail for you. check it

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot - I will check it in a few hours and will accept the answer if it works!

Comment: @Janmenjaya Thanks man. I have spent more than 3 hours for that.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Images are outdated. Add a single resizable Launch Screen and you will always get native resolution in iOS 8 (which is oldest OS the iPhone 6 will run anyway).

Go to File > New > File > iOS User Interface > Launch Screen.

Make a Storyboard launch screen. This will work for any sized screen, present or future.

Go to the "General" tab for your app target.
In the "App Icons and Launch Images" section, choose the Launch Screen File you just made.

Answer (score 0):

Launch images are still necessary if you need to continue to support iOS 7, otherwise the resizable launch screen (storyboard) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Janmenjaya‘s answer is right，but not complete in some cases. After what Janmenjaya suggest to do,go to TARGETS->General->App Icons and Launch Images->Launch Images Source ,then choose the launch image name.Next time run the project ,the height will be right.